# Porque el boton no ejectura mi funcion?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema, al hacer click en el boton **update position** no ejecuta la funcion **updatePosition**

estoy trabajando con maps, acorte parte del codigo

html

```
  <button style="position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;" id="stbutton">Update Position</button>
```

JS

```
    <script type="module">
 $(document).ready(function() {
let map;
let marker;

function updatePosition(newLat, newLng) {
    alert('Its work');
    const latLng = {
        lat: newLat,
        lng: newLng
    };
    // alert(latLng);
    marker.setPosition(latLng);
    map.setCenter(latLng);
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Y en qué parte asignas `updatePosition`como función que se ejecuta al hacer click en el botón?

Comment: Lo que no veo es el evento (por ejemplo click), si tienes la funcion que es el manejador de eventos solo te faltaría crear el evento para ejecutar esa función

Answer (score 1):

Pueda que tu enfoque para entrar al JS lo estés haciendo con el `ID` del elemento y no declarando un `onclick` en el botón, si ese es el caso puedes usar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stbutton').on('click', function() {
        alert('Its work');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="position: relative; z-index: 10000;" id="stbutton">Update Position</button>
```

Ojo que estas usando **JQuery** y debes tener enlazado JQuery en tu proyecto.

Por otro lado si vas a usar JS puro solo con referencia a elementos, debes hacer algo como:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#stbutton");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    alert('Its work');
});
```

```html
<button style="position: relative; z-index: 10000;" id="stbutton">Update Position</button>
```

Y si vas a usar JS puro de la manera tradicional, debes asociar a tu elemento una función:

```js
function myScript() {
    alert('Its work');
}
```

```html
<!-- Fijate que en el evento click voy a desplegar mi función -->
<button style="position: relative; z-index: 10000;" id="stbutton" onclick="myScript()">Update Position</button>
```

Y listo, espero te ayude a entender las diferencias de lo que tu tienes ahora mismo.